# MySQL - Column Order Programmatically

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by, union

I am retrieving **product records / sales order** from a database. I am joining table results using MySQL's **UNION** feature.

If I **set** my query to **retrieve only 1 product** the order of columns looks good. Attached is a screenshot link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJRAb.png

[image]

However, I want to retrieve **1 or more products**. If i set my query to return 1 or more products.. The order of columns is messed up andd looks like the screenshot link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHRTg.png

[image]

This is the query that i used:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_qty' AS meta_key, 1 AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_tax_class' AS meta_key, '' AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bsb.ORDER_ID AS meta_id, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_item_id, '_product_id' AS meta_key, bsb.PRODUCT_ID AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_basket bsb
WHERE bsb.ORDER_id IN(832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_variation_id' AS meta_key, '' AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_line_subtotal' AS meta_key, '' AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_line_total' AS meta_key, '' AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_line_tax' AS meta_key, 0 AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_line_subtotal_tax' AS meta_key, 0 AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id, bso.ID AS order_item_id, 'method_id' AS meta_key, bsd.NAME AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
LEFT OUTER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
WHERE bso.ID IN (832, 830)
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id, bso.ID AS order_item_id, 'cost' AS meta_key, bsd.PRICE AS meta_value
FROM b_sale_order bso
LEFT OUTER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
WHERE bso.ID IN (832, 830)
) sales_order_meta
```

**Note:** I still want the ordering of columns to look like the first link / image even if there are 1 or more products returned.

Kindly Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean ordering of rows, not columns. If you want rows in a particular order you must use an order by statement, otherwise the DBMS is free to return the rows in any order. I.e.

```
select ... from (
    ...
    LEFT OUTER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
    WHERE bso.ID IN (832, 830)
) sales_order_meta
order by ...
```

As a side-note, don't use `select *`

If you want to arrange the result meta_id by meta_id and in a way that reflects the order of the unions you can add an ordering attribute (say origin) to each union like:

```
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_qty' AS meta_key, 1 AS meta_value
         , 1 as origin
    FROM b_sale_order bso
    WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
    UNION
    SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id, '_tax_class' AS meta_key, '' AS  meta_value
         , 2 as origin
    FROM b_sale_order bso
    WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
    UNION
    ...
)
order by meta_id, origin
```

For efficiency reasons I would suggest something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM(
    SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id,  bso.ID AS order_item_id
        ,  x.meta_key, x.meta_value, x.meta_key_order
    FROM b_sale_order bso
    CROSS JOIN ( select '_qty' AS meta_key, 1 AS meta_value, 1 as meta_key_order
                 union
                 select '_tax_class' AS meta_key, '' AS meta_value, 2 as meta_key_order
                 union
                 select '_variation_id' AS meta_key, '' AS meta_value, 4 as meta_key_order
                 union
                 select '_line_subtotal' AS meta_key, '' AS meta_value, 5 as meta_key_order
                 union
                 ...
               ) as x 
    WHERE bso.ID IN(832, 830)
   UNION
   -- 8
   SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id, bso.ID AS order_item_id, 'method_id' AS meta_key, bsd.NAME AS meta_value, 8 as meta_key_order
   FROM b_sale_order bso
   LEFT OUTER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID 
   WHERE bso.ID IN (832, 830)
   UNION
   -- 9
   SELECT bso.ID AS meta_id, bso.ID AS order_item_id, 'cost' AS meta_key, bsd.PRICE AS    meta_value, 9 as meta_key_order
   FROM b_sale_order bso
   LEFT OUTER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
   WHERE bso.ID IN (832, 830)
   -- 3
  SELECT bsb.ORDER_ID AS meta_id, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_item_id, '_product_id' AS meta_key, bsb.PRODUCT_ID AS meta_value, 3 as meta_key_order
  FROM b_sale_basket bsb
  WHERE bsb.ORDER_id IN(832, 830)
) sales_order_meta
order by meta_id, meta_key_order
```

Comment: Hi Lennart, Thanks for the response. Yes, you are right. What i mean was to order the rows like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xJRAb.png even if there are 1 or more products returned.. I tried using order by but it is disarranged.. Do you know of other alternatives to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'll update my answer with a suggestion (not sure I completely understand though)

Comment: meta_key_ordering might be a better name than origin, just a thought

Comment: Hi Lennart, You are indeed a quick thinker. Your answer works.. But in the Final Output, i don't really need to show the origin column.. do you know of any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, replace `select *` with the columns you need, say `select meta_id,  order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value`. See also my suggestion on how to make your query more efficient (reducing the number of accesses against b_sale_order)

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by` on the result of the `join`s:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    ...
    ) sales_order_meta
ORDER BY order_item_id, meta_key
```

Comment: Hi P5Coder, I'll try to use your answer in my phpmyadmin. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I tried your answer. After ordering them by ORDER BY order_item_id, meta_key .. I also want to order the rows like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xJRAb.png for each product .. do you know how to do this?